# Newtsonsoft.Json - Deserialize JSON with nested arrays to DataTable

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, datatable

I Need to convert the following Json string to DataTable.

Json example:

```
[
    {
        'extension': '0001',
        'name': 'User 1',
        'email': 'user1@mail.se',
        'mobile': '+46000000',
        'profile': {
        'available': false,
        'name': 'Gone for the day',
        'until': '2017-09-01 08:00:00',
        'message': 'Do not call me'
    },
        'calls': [],
    },
    {
        'extension': '0002',
        'name': 'User 2',
        'email': 'user2@mail.se',
        'mobile': '+46000000',
        'profile': {
        'available': false,
        'name': 'Gone for the day',
        'until': '2017-09-01 08:00:00',
        'message': 'Do not call me'
    },
        'calls': [],
    }
]
```

I am able to read everything before 'profile':, how do i access next level of data in under profile? (profile.avialable,profile.name, profile.until, profile.message) and add this to datatable ?

This is my classes

```
public class Profile
{
    public bool available { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string until { get; set; }
    public object message { get; set; }
}


public class RootObject
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string extension { get; set; }
    public string mobile { get; set; }
    public Profile profile { get; set; }
}
```

And this is my code

```
public static DataTable ToDataTable<T>(List<T> items)
{
    DataTable dataTable = new DataTable(typeof(T).Name);

    //Get all the properties
    System.Reflection.PropertyInfo[] Props = typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
    foreach (PropertyInfo prop in Props)
    {
        //Defining type of data column gives proper data table 
        var type = (prop.PropertyType.IsGenericType && prop.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>) ? Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(prop.PropertyType) : prop.PropertyType);
        //Setting column names as Property names
        dataTable.Columns.Add(prop.Name, type);
    }
    foreach (T item in items)
    {
        var values = new object[Props.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < Props.Length; i++)
        {
            //inserting property values to datatable rows
            values[i] = Props[i].GetValue(item, null);
        }
        dataTable.Rows.Add(values);
    }
    //put a breakpoint here and check datatable
    return dataTable;
}


PopulateList()
{          
    var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(JsonData);
    DataTable dt = ToDataTable(data);

    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Where JsonData contains my JSON

Anyone got a clue?

Comment: What is the actual problem? What do you mean by saying "how to access next level"? Where you want to access it?

Comment: If actual problem is nested class conversion to DataTable (nothing to do with deserialization and json!) then do you really need DataTable? Can't you use List/BindingList? Yes, there are many questions, because your question is vague.

Comment: You are right, the question might be vague, the json is from a API of a phone swtichboard and the goal is to create a dynamic phone list with contacts and the profile info. it needs to be a table
with columns  Name, Extension, mobile, profile.avialable, profile.name, profile.until

Comment: Here's the starter for you: [C# Reflection: Get Property Value of Nested Classes](http://mcgivery.com/c-reflection-get-property-value-of-nested-classes/)

Answer (score 0):

Json is working fine

```
    string JsonData = @"[
        {
        'extension': '0001',
        'name': 'User 1',
        'email': 'user1@mail.se',
        'mobile': '+46000000',
        'profile': {
        'available': false,
        'name': 'Gone for the day',
        'until': '2017-09-01 08:00:00',
        'message': 'Do not call me'
        },
        }
        ]";
    var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(JsonData);
```

`RootObjects` contains valid `Profile` objectsm the problem is not with Json parser. In `dataTable.Rows.Add(values);`, your `values` propety is 'valid' (it contains correct and populated `Profile` objects). Check if you are using a valid method for passing data into your database.

Comment: If i try to bind data directly to a gridview without converting it ti datatable i get data for extension, name,email,mobile running your example.

Comment: How do i rewrite the public static DataTable ToDataTable<T>(List<T> items) function to handle the profile values?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm getting this correctly, you want to display the data under "Profile" in the same row so each row would look like {"name", "extension", "mobile", "profile.available", "profile.name", "profile.until", "profile.message"}.

The issue is that the code is adding columns based on the type of objects in the RootObject class (name, extension, mobile, profile) and is not looking further into their types to see whether they further have any properties or not.

In this section of the code:

```
foreach (PropertyInfo prop in Props)
{
    var type = (prop.PropertyType.IsGenericType && prop.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>) ? Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(prop.PropertyType) : prop.
    dataTable.Columns.Add(prop.Name, type);
}
```

You will have to add a check to see if objects in the RootObject have any further properties.
Based on that you will have to change your second loop as well to account for sub-properties to add to each row of data in the table.

Comment: How do i rewrite the public static DataTable ToDataTable<T>(List<T> items) function to handle the profile values?

Comment: No one has a example how to do this?